# Migrate 260 tables from ingres to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ingres

I am migrating an ingres database to SQL Server.

This database has 260 tables to migrate.

I usually use SSIS, I create a package for each table, that will be 260 packages, and then I run one by one for SSIS itself.

I would like to know if you have an easier and faster way to do this migration?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try the Oracle Migration Assistant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You could look into using BIML to help with the repetitive task of creating all those packages.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was informed now that it's not Oracle, it's Ingres.

Comment: Not affilaited with them, but this is the first result on Google for "ingres database to sql server migration" https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto/ingres-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way is to use the **SQL Server Import and Export wizard**, since it allows migrating multiple tables in one operation:

- [How to copy multiple tables from ingres database to sqlserver database ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bfd2556a-946e-4a74-8c34-be9a4938fd3f/how-to-copy-multiple-tables-from-ingres-database-to-sqlserver-database-?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

You should use SSMA for oracle
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm sorry, I was informed now that it's not Oracle, it's Ingres